# Default parameter using another parameter

Tags: c++, default-value

The following code is not valid in C++

```
struct Test {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void function(Test A, int n = A.x) {
    ...
}
```

because the default parameter A.x depends upon A. Is there a way to go around this limitation? The reason why I want to do this is the following. I have a class Vector that behaves very closely to std::vector but has a member allocator_ which is responsible for allocating memory. My copy constructor takes 2 parameters:

```
Vector(const Vector& A, Allocator& allocator) {
    ...
}
```

Such copy constructors are allowed by the standard if the second parameter has a default value. But I want the default value for allocator to be A.allocator_ which is why I've tried

```
Vector(const Vector& A, Allocator& allocator = A.allocator_) {
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, it is not valid C++. Does any one of you have a solution for this problem?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `Vector(const Vector& A, Allocator& allocator):allocator(A.allocator_){...}`?

Comment: An overload, perhaps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use an overload instead of default arguments:

```
void function(Test A, int n) {
    ...
}

void function(Test A) {
    function(A, A.x);
}
```

Comment: It is so obvious I wonder why I did not think about it. Maybe overloading a copy constructor was against my feelings. But it works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like that?
You can just use default value,
    void function(Test A, int n = 0) 
    {
        n=A.x;
        ...
    }